# Is it possible to reproduce visibility bug?

Tags: java, spring, concurrency

i have two classes SomeService and Dependency configured and wired via Spring:

```
@Named
public class SomeService implements Service
{

    @Inject
    public Dependency dependency;

    public void execute()
    {
        dependency.execute();
    }
}



@Named
public class Dependency
{
    public void execute()
    {

    }
}
```

In some rare cases SomeService.execute() throws NPE. I guess that problem is non-final/non-volatile field can't be accessed from different threads without external synchronization. The pretty obvious fix is to make Dependency field final and replace field injection with constructor injection. But i was trying to reproduce the initial bug on my local machine using one thread initiating the ApplicationContext and few other threads trying to get SomeService. In all cases dependency has never been null. Is it even possible to make the test case reproducing the problem? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: To begin with, you can make `dependency` a `private` field. My guess is that either you are setting it to `null` somewhere, or you are creating a `Service` instance without using dependency (`new SomeService`) elsewhere. Make the field `private` and create a non-default constructor (don't create a parameterless one) and check what is no longer compiling.

Comment: This is just a short example of real classes. In real class field is private and the SomeService class is instantiated using the org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory#getBean(java.lang.Class<T>).

Comment: You could also use constructor injection to make them final.

Comment: Thank you, but i already mentioned that solution is obvious and i'm actually trying to find the way to reproduce such bugs.

Comment: even with unsafe publishing lack of final/volatile is unlikely to be easily reproducible on x86/64. The problem is likely in the code and accessing uninitialized objects

Answer (score 0):

Concurrency bugs like this are sometimes hard to reproduce on single-socket hardware since the time during which core *see* different values at memory locations is short, due to shared (L3) caches. On multi-socket server hardware, it may be easier since the time to synchronize memory across nodes is longer. This is also what limits scalability on larger machines. If you develop and test on small machines, but run on big iron, this will bite you a lot.

Anyway, this is a classic concurrency trap and easily avoided by using `final`, as you and others have mentioned.

So, you may see it easier/more often on multi-socket hardware, but there is of course no guarantee.

Comment: Ok, thank you all, i was just wondering is there any good way to reproduce such problems.